# Kubernetes - PVC - How to recover accidentally deleted files

Tags: file, kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

I have a PVC mounted on a pod. someone from my team has deleted files from it. Is there a way to recover those files?
Also, can we find who deleted the files?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to recover those files?

Persistent Volumes and Persistent Volume Claims are only APIs provided by Kubernetes. Below these APIs, there is a storage system that **may** or **may not** implement backup features or mirroring. Check the documentation for your cloud provider or your on-prem storage systems.